# Error (10500): VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i have problem with this code !!!

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tl2 is
    port( clk: in std_logic );
end tl2;

architecture ways2 of tl2 is
    component counter is
        generic(
            n: natural :=5
        ); port(
            clock:  in std_logic;
            clear:  in std_logic;
            count:  in std_logic;
            Q:  out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    component tff is
        port(
            t: in  std_logic;
            clock: in std_logic;
            output: out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal x: std_logic;
    i: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    ta , tb , tc: std_logic;
    tap , tbp , tcp: std_logic;

begin

    counter4: counter port map( clk => clock , '0' => clear , '1' => count , i => Q);
    A: tff port map(clk => clock , ta => t , tap => output);
    B: tff port map(clk => clock , tb => t , tbp => output);
    C: tff port map(clk => clock , tc => t , tcp => output);

    process( i.ta,tb,tc )
    begin
        if( i="00011" or i="00110" or i="10101" ) then
            x <= '1';
        end if;
        if( i="10101" ) then
            clear <= '0';
        end if;
        ta <= ((tbp and tcp and x)or(tap and tcp and x));
        tb <= (not tap and tcp and x);
        tc <= x;

    end process;

end ways2;
```

---

user3139746 elaborated on the errors he was asking about in a comment in response to sharth's comment:

> thats error:Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at tl2.vhd(27) near text
>   "i"; expecting "begin", or a declaration statement Error (10500): VHDL
>   syntax error at tl2.vhd(33) near text "=>"; expecting ")", or "," – 
>   user3139746 4 hours ago

(This is an Altera error message)

Comment: It's nice that you have a problem. You should tell us what it is.

Comment: thats error:Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at tl2.vhd(27) near text "i";  expecting "begin", or a declaration statement
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at tl2.vhd(33) near text "=>";  expecting ")", or ","

Comment: line 27 is line 2 here and line 33 is line 8 too

Comment: Keyword "signal" is required before each separate signal declaration.  You either need components for each of your instances or change your instances to "direct entity instantiation".

Answer (score 0):

The reserved word signal is required signal declarations in these block declarative items:

```
end component;

    signal x: std_logic;
    signal i: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);  -- added reserved word signal
    signal ta , tb , tc: std_logic;          -- added reserved word signal
    signal tap , tbp , tcp: std_logic;       -- added reserved word signal

begin
```

Those get rid of your 10500 syntax errors, (there are more):

ghdl -a tl2.vhdl
tl2.vhdl:31:36: no declaration for "clock"
tl2.vhdl:31:51: no declaration for "clear"
tl2.vhdl:31:66: no declaration for "count"
tl2.vhdl:31:79: no declaration for "q"
tl2.vhdl:32:24: no declaration for "clock"
tl2.vhdl:32:38: no declaration for "t"
tl2.vhdl:32:49: no declaration for "output"
tl2.vhdl:33:24: no declaration for "clock"
tl2.vhdl:33:38: no declaration for "t"
tl2.vhdl:33:49: no declaration for "output"
tl2.vhdl:34:24: no declaration for "clock"
tl2.vhdl:34:38: no declaration for "t"
tl2.vhdl:34:49: no declaration for "output"
tl2.vhdl:36:12: signal "i" does not designate a record
tl2.vhdl:42:13: no declaration for "clear"

Your formals and actuals were reversed in your component  instantiations:

```
counter4: 
counter port map ( 
            clock => clk,
            clear => '0',
            count => '1',
            Q =>i
        );
            --- clk => clock , '0' => clear , '1' => count , i => Q);
A: 
    tff 
        port map (
            clock => clk,
            t => ta,
            output => tap
        );
            -- clk => clock , ta => t , tap => output);
B: 
    tff 
        port map (
            clock => clk,
            t => tb,
            output => tbp
        );
            -- clk => clock , tb => t , tbp => output);
C: 
    tff 
        port map (
            clock => clk,
            t => tc,
            output => tcp
            );
            --  clk => clock , tc => t , tcp => output);
```

Notice that with named association the order doesn't have to match component declarations.

tl2.vhdl:64:12: signal "i" does not designate a record:

```
    process( i,tap,tbp, tcp, x )          -- process( i.ta,tb,tc )
    begin
        if i = "00011" or i = "00110" or i = "10101"  then
            x <= '1';
        end if;
        if  i = "10101" then
            clear <= '0';
        end if;
        ta <= ((tbp and tcp and x)or(tap and tcp and x));
        tb <= (not tap and tcp and x);
        tc <= x;

    end process;
```

Note that every signal from the right hand side of a signal assignment or evaluated in an if statement condition expression has been added to the sensitivity list.  (And about now someone is bound to pipe in that in VHDL 2008 you could use the keyword `all` in place of individual elements in the sensitivity list).

ghdl -a tl2.vhdl
tl2.vhdl:70:13: no declaration for "clear"

Notice clear is defined as an input to `tl2`.  Did you mean an assignment to `x` here:

```
    if( i="10101" ) then
        x <= '0';          -- clear <= '0';
    end if;
```

You could also note that no where do you have an assignment to `i`.  The default value for i would be "UUUUU" which would guarantee none of the condition evaluations in the if statements would result in an assignment.  You need to play 'Where's Waldo' with `i` yet.

It isn't clear how sharth mutilated the code example, it appears he accepted a just-checking-you-were-paying-attention test case blindly.  (I restored it, before someone down voted your question, before I save this answer).

Error 10500 is a catch all syntax error, where one could imagine the preposition is that someone would resort to authoritative VHDL texts (e.g. the LRM) to resolve issues with syntax.  In general error messages don't teach languages and it's an extra effort to analyze syntax errors for an actual cause, not required by the VHDL standard where a VHDL design specification can be analyzed with a look ahead of one lexical token.

You can see from the text of the first error message it interpreted `i:` as a label which can precede any statement - other than a declarative item.  The error message leaves something to be desired.  The second error text is no more enlightening than the first.

The fault lies in the quality of error messages and likely reinforces the idea that the user will at least resort to a syntax summary to resolve syntax errors.  See [Hyperlinked VHDL-93 BNF Syntax](http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/tools/grammar/vhdl93-bnf.html) or [EBNF Syntax: VHDL'93](http://www.externsoft.ch/download/vhdl.html) (I don't currently know of a useful syntax summary for VHDL-2008).

Using the EBNF as a reference has the interesting side effect of giving us common language to discuss VHDL syntax, useful for describing errors and fixes.